# Current scroll position when using -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch - Safari iOS javascript event (scrollTop / scrollLeft)

Tags: javascript, ios

I'm using -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch to make a div with overflow:scroll; scroll smoothly through iOS touch events.

It works brilliantly, except it doesn't seem to update element.scrollTop or element.scrollLeft while it's scrolling. It only updates element.scrollTop / triggers a scroll event when the momentum runs out and it stops.

Does anyone know of a way of finding out its current scroll position and if there's an event I can listen for? I wondered if it can be found through a CSS3 property perhaps? Thanks

Example below showing two attempts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div id="display_a">Scroll is: 0</div>
    <div id="display_b">Scroll is: 0</div>  
    <div id="element" style="width:800px;overflow-x:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;">
        <div style="font-size:100px;width:1850px;">
            a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var e = document.getElementById("element");
        var display_a = document.getElementById("display_a");
        var display_b = document.getElementById("display_b");
        e.addEventListener("scroll",function(event){display_a.innerHTML = "Scroll is: " + event.target.scrollLeft;});
        setInterval(function(){display_b.innerHTML = "Scroll is: " +  e.scrollLeft;},100);
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

**============ UPDATE ============**

iOS 8 has sorted this behaviour. Scroll events are now triggered while scrolling.

Note that you'll now have to deal with negative scroll values during the bounce scroll.

Comment: Just wanted to say a big thank you to everyone who's contributed so far, I fear we're not going to find a perfect solution but there are some good suggestions below.

Comment: The problem still exists on 3rd-party browsers on iOS >8.x

Comment: Scroll events don't fire in homescreen webapps or UIWebView

Answer (score 10):

In the iOS Developer Library, there is an explanation in the Safari guidelines about it:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Basically, the event flow for the scrolling goes like this:
touch/start dragging(mousewheel event)-> pan/movement(no events) -> stop(onscroll)

So there is nothing like a continuous event of scrolling being triggered while the pan happens there just an onScroll at the end of the gesture.

If you find an optional way to accomplish that, let me know :)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still no closer on this one, but will certainly let everyone know if and when I find a solution. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

This might help.  It's a jQuery solution that I'm using to force pagination on IOS side-to-side swipes.  It's not exactly the same case as you're working.  I'm using the "overflow-scrolling:auto" which does not behave like the "touch" version.

```
#yourDiv {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

I use "overflow-scrolling:auto" because it reacts quicker to the touchend event.  Unfortunatley, "overflow-scrolling:touch" does indeed seem to resist javascript and CSS animation while it's in motion.  But at least you can get some location information out of it during the scroll.

```
var pageSwiping = false;

$('#yourDiv').on('scroll', function(e) {
    if (pageSwiping !== true  ) {
        pageSwiping = true;
        var offset = $('#'+e.target.id).scrollLeft();
        $('#yourDiv').one( 'touchend',{elem:e.target.id,dragStart:offset},divMove);
    };
});

var divMove = function(e) {
    pageSwiping = false;
    var elem = e.data.elem;
    var dragEnd = $('#'+elem).scrollLeft();
    var dragDelta = (dragEnd - e.data.dragStart)
        // Make page-alignment decisions based on dragDelta
};
```

Comment: Hi Matt, just picked up this answer. It is a possible solution, but I love the feel of the native iOS scroll so am really looking to keep that (without trying to replicate the drag momentum code the iOS does so well). Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

In a similar situation I am using [scrollability.js](http://www.scrollability.com), which does a really nice job simulating the native scrolling behavior. I'm then listening for the 'scrollability-start' event and monitoring the top/left attributes of the scrolled element. I know it's not ideal, but it's a decent alternative.

Comment: I have to say, it does actually do a pretty good job simulating iOS style scrolling! I'll certainly take a proper look at some point. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: also take a look at [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4), which does the same thing, but i found more useful because of methods like scrollTo() and scrollToElement().

Answer (score 1):

Here is my repository where I've added the callback `onScrolling()` to let me know when the momentum scrolling animation is occurring in `animate()`: https://github.com/simpleshadow/iscroll/blob/master/src/iscroll.js

I've made an example app using his suggestion here: http://jsfiddle.net/simpleshadow/wQQEM/22/

@robertlawson86 on Github made this suggestion to help provide an idea on when to grab the position during momentum scrolling. See example and discussion: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/183

Answer (score 0):

I know is weird, but you can keep track of scrollLeft/scrollTop just by registering touchstart event:

```
e.addEventListener("touchstart",function(event){});
```

Comment: Thanks David, but surely this don't help after you've taken your finger of the touch screen and it's just the momentum that's keeping it scrolling. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Get the position of a horizontal scroller while srolling ( via css overflow-y:scroll )

```
$('#myNode').bind('scroll', function(e){
  var myPos = e.target.scrollLeft;
  // do something with myPos but don't naughty
})
```

Comment: This assumes a jQuery dependency

Answer (score -1):

If it helps, scrollTop and scrollLeft are updated in real-time within the touchmove event handler:

```
$(function()
{
    var $div = $("#scroll")
    var $p   = $("#display");

    var update = function(e)
    {
        $p.text( e.type +": "+ $div.scrollLeft() +", "+ $div.scrollTop() );
    }

    $div.bind( "touchmove", update )
        .bind( "scroll",    update );
});
```

Comment: Just to note, if you want this for keeping elements static on the screen, position:fixed CSS was introduced with iOS 5.

Comment: This assumes a jQuery dependency

Comment: JQuery was used for a short working demonstration; scrollTop, scrollLeft and touchmove are standard without it.